# Hikari Cp Micronaut Framework Configuration?

Tags: postgresql, micronaut, hikaricp, micronaut-client

Problem Statement

1. We are using the Micronaut framework, and I want to override the default HikariCP connection           pool, but it is not working. How can we achieve this?
2. Alternatively, how can we close the default HikariCP connection pool in this framework? we have Implemented multi-tenancy and we have created Custom Hikari Cp for that !!
3. The logging isn't functioning.

Micronaut version :- 3.7.4
database : PostgreSQl

Here is The Custom HikariCp for multi-tenancy Code

```
        public DataSource createAndConfigureDataSource(String tenantName, String username, String password){
                logger.info ("Creating a new DataSource for tenant "+tenantName );
                HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
                ds.setUsername(username);
                ds.setPassword(password);
                ds.setJdbcUrl(MultiTenantConnectionProvider.DEFAULT_URL+tenantName) ;
                ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                ds.setConnectionTimeout(20000);
                // Minimum number of idle connections in the pool
                ds.setMinimumIdle(2);
                // Maximum number of actual connection in the pool
                ds.setMaximumPoolSize(15);
                ds.setSchema("public");
                // Maximum time that a connection is allowed to sit idle in the pool
                ds.setIdleTimeout(300000);
                ds.setLeakDetectionThreshold(2100);
                ds.setConnectionTimeout(20000);
                // Setting up a pool name for each tenant datasource
                String tenantConnectionPoolName = tenantName + " -connection-pool";
                ds.setPoolName(tenantConnectionPoolName);
                return ds;
            }
```

Here is application.yml file code

```
            datasources:
              default:
                driver-class-name: postgresDriver
                db-type: postgres
                dialect: POSTGRES
                url: jdbc://postgesdatabse url
                driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
                username: ##
                password: ##
                hikari:
                  maximumPoolSize: 30
                  connectionTimeout: 30000
                  autocommit: false
                  maxLifetime: 30000
                  idleTimeout: 30000
                  minimumIdle: 3
                  log-connections: true
                  log-stack-traces: true
                  logging:
                    level:
                      com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig: DEBUG
                      com.zaxxer.hikari: TRACE
```

Unable to find Solution!!